# Converting data lines columns to values in python

Tags: python, string, split, int, strip

how do i use **enemurate** or some other function to return these values in a txt file i input to python as a whole string

```
TW11 42.83 -72.94   2.1

TW22 41.727 -75.81 3.9
```

my work so far is

```
in_file =open('tow.txt','r')

for line in_infile:
    L=line.strip().split()
    Tower = L[0]
    Lat = L[1]
    Long = L[2]
    ComDis = L[3]

print (Tower,Lat,Long,ComDis)
```

however i can only return the first line of the input file, there are about 20 lines in the file just wanted to give a short example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, indentation matters. You're printing only last line. If you want to print each line, move your print inside the for look by indenting it:

```
in_file =open('tow.txt','r')

for line in_infile:
    L=line.strip().split()
    Tower = L[0]
    Lat = L[1]
    Long = L[2]
    ComDis = L[3]

    print (Tower,Lat,Long,ComDis)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! do you know how i print just the first line of the whole output, im trying Tower[1] or Tower[0:4] and its only giving me the first 4 letters of the line?

Comment: I don't get it, you want to print first line from file, or you want to print Tower for each line?

Comment: I got it, I just did  """print Tower   """ and printed all the values, 22 rows straight down

Comment: just asked another question on the assignments second part maybe you can help there also if you have time